# How to wait for a SQL Server database copy

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure, automated-tests, azure-sql-database

My powershell deployment script creates a copy of a reference Azure database to run some integration tests against:

```
create database MyTest1 as copy of MyRefDb
```

The problem is that the new db is not immediately available:

> Database 'MyTest1' on server 'abc' is not currently
>   available.  Please retry the connection later.

A similar problem exists when I try to drop `MyTest1` with `drop database` command, it doesn't happen immediately unlike as on local (on-premise) SQL Server instance.

How do I *reliably* wait for my Azure test database availability in a script when altering its state?

Answer (score 2):

To check the status of a copy operation, you can query `sys.databases` and `sys.dm_database_copies` views on the new database.

When the copy operation is in progress, `state_desc` column's value of `sys.databases` view will be `COPYING`.

If the copy operation is successful, the value will be `ONLINE`.

In case of failure, the value will be `SUSPECT`.

Please see this for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy-transact-sql.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually easy with powershell

```
Write-Output "Start database copy"
$dbCopy = Start-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName $ServerName -DatabaseName $SourceDbName -PartnerDatabase $targetDbName

try
{ 
    WHILE ($dbCopy)
    {               
        Sleep 10
        Write-Output "Check if it's done"
        $dbCopy = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName $ServerName -DatabaseCopy $dbCopy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Write-Output "$dbCopy"
        # Sleep 10 seconds
    }
    $Copy_DB = Get-AzureSqlDatabase -ServerName $ServerName -DatabaseName $targetDbName
    Write-Output "COPY Completed"
}
catch{ Throw "FAILED: Cannot Get-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy" }
```